# How to compile bootstrap-material-design sass files with gulp?

Tags: sass, gulp

I have been struggling with gulp to compile scss files into css.

I havn't used gulp and sass very much and the docs of this particular framework are not helpful on this matter.

My gulpfile looks like this

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var scssFile='assets/scss/bootstrap-material-design.scss';
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(scssFile)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/css'));
});
```

I did `npm install gulp gulp-sass --save-dev` to install libraries.
And I copied the content of this folder https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/tree/master/scss into a folder named "scss"

Now running `gulp sass` gives me this error:

> [13:54:37] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/imb4/gulpfile.js
>   [13:54:37] Starting 'sass'...
>   Error in plugin "sass"
>   Message:
>       assets/scss/_variables.scss
>   Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/functions.
>           on line 56 of assets/scss/_variables.scss
>           from line 2 of assets/scss/_core.scss
>           from line 3 of assets/scss/bootstrap-material-design.scss
>   >> @import "~bootstrap/scss/functions"; // from bootstrap node_module
>      ^
>   [13:54:37] Finished 'sass' after 50 ms

Is this because I copied the wrong scss folder ?

Do I need to `npm install bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1`? 
(I did try that, but I can't `require()` it because it needs jQuery or something.)

Do I need to reference the scss files that are in the node_modules?

The error says it needs a bootstrap folder, do I need to download bootstrap scss files manually and copy them in the folder? Do I have to do `npm install bootstrap`?

It's probably a stupid question, but I'm already stuck on this for hours now.

Comment: I changed "~bootstrap/" with "../../node_modules/bootstrap/" in _variables.scss and _core.scss and it worked. But that seems like a hack: I should not be modifying those files, should I?

Answer (score 0):

Clone the folder in the link as is to your assets/scss

Your gulpfile should call your main entry sass file style.scss - in your case  "bootstrap-material-design.scss"

this sass file contains only one import - @import "core";

_core imports _variables.scss, _mixins.scss etc...

your _variables.scss file has

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions"; // from bootstrap node_module
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables"; // from bootstrap node_module
```

So its looking for a node_modules/bootstrap folder,

```
npm install bootstrap
```

will add it.

when you run your gulp task and the sass starts compiling it needs the full bootstrap files located in node_modules/bootstrap/scss/ folder to compile correctly.

your "bootstrap-material-design.scss" will first import _core, _core will then import _variables, _variables imports a few custom files from another variables folder within the scss directory before looking at your node_modules folder (on line 56) with @import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";

your gulp task will pick up your sass files references (anything with an underscore is compiled at build time) - That spits out a plain css file where ever you set the destination to be eg "assets/css/style.css" which is the file you should reference in your html after build.

if this is still not happening for you you may just have a simple path issue to resolve. bootstrap versions can differ on sass fodler structure so double check your path in node_modules/bootstrap/scss/ actually has a functions folder.

If it does try @import "./node_modules/bootstrap/functions";

If it does not then you may need to check your version of bootstrap.

Eg - with bootstrap 4.1.1 they are imports not folders 
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables';

Comment: I tried `npm install bootstrap --save-dev` but that doesn't change anything. do I need to do `require('bootstrap')` in the gulpfile? (that gives me `Cannot find module 'jquery'`)

Comment: check your node_modules folder - bootstrap should be installed if the command ran without errors. You don't add bootstrap to the gulpfile, it is being referenced from the _variables.scss file.  Check your assets/scss/_variables.scss actually exists (you will need all the files from the scss folder https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/tree/master/scss ) for the @import's to work.

Comment: Yes there is a folder `node_modules/bootstrap/`. But _variables.scss is in `/assets/scss/` so I guess line 56 "~bootstrap/scss/functions" does not point to node_modules folder. (Remember I copied the git repo folder into my project)

Comment: I tried using the scss files from node_modules instead `var scssFile='node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/scss/bootstrap-material-design.scss'` but that just gives the same error, there is no "~bootstrap/scss/functions" folder